# Geolocation based on IP

Tags: angular, google-maps, geoip, angular-google-maps

I am working on Angular Google Maps to plot the geolocation based on IP address and using [ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io/) to provide that IP address.

I would like to know why when I get the IP address on ipinfo.io and plot it in google maps using Angular Google Maps, the lat and long seems not accurate or somehow close to the current location.

---

You can try to get your current IP address on https://www.whatismyip.com/ and then try to put it in my project then you will see the geolocation.

but what I wanted to achieve is the output here https://mycurrentlocation.net/index.php

Is there a way that I can get an accurate geolocation based on IP?

---

Please see this live code on Stackblitz.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/dmgrave-ng-geolocation-by-ip-v1

Comment: What do you mean they "seem not accurate" ?  How do you know that?

Comment: @BooberBunz please see the update on my question. I am not sure if it is possible to get an accurate geolocation based on IP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my research I think this will explain well..
Based on [how-can-i-detect-real-location-of-the-user-through-their-ip-address](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/108885/how-can-i-detect-real-location-of-the-user-through-their-ip-address).

> Geo-ip location accuracy varies wildly from country to country and
>   from provider to provider. Some smaller countries have very accurate
>   internal mappings of IP's to postal addresses but this type of data is
>   generally not available to the public.
>
> Note: Different Geo-IP address databases may also have different
>   location data for the same IP address so you may also want to
>   double-check the quality of your source data.

---

I need to use [**HTML5 Geolocation**](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp) especially if the remote device is a mobile device with GPS or GPS like triangulation features this may give you much more accurate info than the Geo-IP address.

and then

To be able to get the exact/accurate location is that the user need to have a mobile device with GPS and the user need to allow to [share](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/142065?hl=en) their location.

> **Important Note:** Geolocation is most accurate for devices with GPS.

---

This article ([Ip geolocation is almost accurate (reliable), but not 100%](https://support.clickmeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/211035626-How-accurate-reliable-is-IP-GeoLocation-)) shows the reason why geolocation is not accurate.

```
The main reasons for this variation in result is because: 

IP is traced from Provider or organization registration
Use of proxies by the user hides the exact location
Not updated data in the registrar IP database (whois information)
```

---

Based on [whatismyip](https://www.whatismyip.com/ip-address-geolocation-incorrect/)

> If you lookup your IP address and the city you live in is not shown,
>   but the city 10 miles away where your ISP is located does, then your
>   IP address geolocation data is about as accurate as it's going to get.

Answer (score 1):

You are using coordinates from an IP geolocation API which has less accuracy compare to Wifi geolocation or GPS.

Unless you can access to the end user GPS data, then you must use a third party service to translate IP address or WIFI MAC address to get latitude and longitude.

Below are 2 proposal to solve your problem.

1) Request end user to share their GPS location through HTML 5. In this case, web browser will request authorization from end user before sharing the coordinates to you (subject to availability). You can visit http://ipgeo5.com for sample codes.

2) Change another geolocation database. If coverage and accuracy is your concern, you can evaluate other database providers. You can visit http://lite.ip2location.com and use their IP2Location LITE database and see if it meet your requirements. If you prefer web API, then you can consider https://www.ipinfodb.com

Comment: Thanks your your answer will try to implement your proposal then I'll get back to you.

Comment: I have tried to implement your answer both 1 and 2 but it is still not accurate like it shows the exact geolocation about 6KM away from the exact geolocation.